# Merge objects in array by ID javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I am trying to merge 2 arrays of objects by ID-s (`ID` and `AUTOMOBIL`) with this code I only push last `array of objects(OPREMA)`. Someone have any idea how can I get all of them in the spot they should be?

So when `ID` in `a1` is `== 1` I need all of `OPREMA` in `a2` witch `AUTOMOBIL` is equal to `1` to save it together it `a1`, but with this code it's only saving last one.

```js
const a1 = [
  { ID: "2", TIP: "A3", VRSTA: "Limousine", $$hashKey: "object:3" },
  { ID: "1", TIP: "A5", VRSTA: "Coupe", $$hashKey: "object:7" },
];

const a2 = [
  {
    AUTOMOBIL: "1",
    OPREMA: {
      ID: "5",
      NAZIV_OPREME: "Automatski",
      VRSTA_OPREME: "2",
      CIJENA: "15000",
      OPIS: "Automatski mjenjač",
    },
  },
  {
    AUTOMOBIL: "1",
    OPREMA: {
      ID: "3",
      NAZIV_OPREME: "Benzin",
      VRSTA_OPREME: "1",
      CIJENA: "7000",
      OPIS: "Gorivo benzin",
    },
  },
  {
    AUTOMOBIL: "1",
    OPREMA: {
      ID: "19",
      NAZIV_OPREME: "1.0",
      VRSTA_OPREME: "5",
      CIJENA: "7000",
      OPIS: "potrosnja 3-6l",
    },
  },
  {
    AUTOMOBIL: "1",
    OPREMA: {
      ID: "11",
      NAZIV_OPREME: "Sportback",
      VRSTA_OPREME: "3",
      CIJENA: "70000",
      OPIS: "sportski izgled šasije",
    },
  },
  {
    AUTOMOBIL: "1",
    OPREMA: {
      ID: "8",
      NAZIV_OPREME: "Quattro",
      VRSTA_OPREME: "4",
      CIJENA: "15000",
      OPIS: "Pogon na sve kotače",
    },
  },
];

const a3 = a1.map(t1 => ({ ...t1, ...a2.find(t2 => t2.AUTOMOBIL === t1.ID) }));

//RESULT OF a3
console.log(a3);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide an expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you never specified how exactly you want the elements of a2 to be saved in the a1 element. I'm assuming that you need them as a array under the OPREMA property. Your code was pretty close but instead of find you needed to use filter to keep all elements that match.

```
const a3 = a1.map(t1 => {
      const matchingElements = a2.filter(t2 => t2.AUTOMOBIL === t1.ID);
      return ({...t1, OPREMA: matchingElements.map(({ OPREMA }) => OPREMA) });
});
```

Comment: Always a pleasure! But keep the feedback of the others in mind - try to improve on the formulation of the question :)